# How to get indice of 'True' value in Tensorflow based on axis?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to extract indices of 'True' in tensorflow's tensor based on specific axis.

expected value of

> [   [True,False,True,False],
>
> [False,False,True,False]       ]

is

> [[0,2],
>
> [2]]

I found out that

```
'tf.where'
```

is similar to what I expected, but

when I use this funciton, the result was

> [[0, 0],
>          [0, 2],
>          [1, 2]],

is there any way to get indices of 'True' value according to specific axis?

Answer (score 2):

This should give you what you're looking for -

```
import tensorflow as tf

b = tf.constant([[True, False, True, False],[ False, False, True, False]])
x=tf.unstack(b)
c = [tf.squeeze(tf.where(e)) for e in x]

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    print(sess.run([c]))
```

This edit is inspired by chrert's comment on the previous version of my answer. The solution doesn't actually require one to specify the axis, and I have modified it to reflect this(It does however take the axis=0, which may be considered restrictive). He is right that tf.while_loop along with TensorArrays would allow you to loop over a tensor of any given shape without knowing its shape beforehand; and its good to know how to work with dynamically shaped tensors as well ! However, for bj1123's  particular usecase this could fail when trying to stack the results. This is because each row or slice can (and in all probability will!!) have different counts of True and False values. This will raise the error "InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): TensorArray has inconsistent shapes." To quantify what I'm trying to say -

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np



inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.bool, shape=(2,4)) 
time_steps = tf.shape(inputs)[0]
initial_outputs = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=time_steps)
initial_t = tf.placeholder(dtype='int32')

def cond(t, *args):
    return t < time_steps

def body(t, outputs_):
    sub = tf.gather(inputs, t)
    cur = tf.squeeze(tf.cast(tf.where(sub), tf.int32))
    outputs_ = outputs_.write(t, cur)
    return t + 1, outputs_

t, outputs = tf.while_loop(cond, body,[initial_t, initial_outputs])

outputs = outputs.stack()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run([init])
    print(outputs)
    print(sess.run([outputs], feed_dict={inputs: np.asarray([[True,False,True,False],[True, True, False, False]]), initial_t:0}))
```

The above code will run fine, now try replacing the placeholder with

```
np.asarray([[True,True,True,False],[True, True, False, False]])
```

and now you can see the error. There doesn't seem to be any direct way of stacking irregularly shaped tensors into a single tensor. The only way is to have a list of tensors as shown in my first version. 
I have also edited the

Comment: Maybe you should mention that this will only work, if the the dimension of the axis is known at graph construction. Maybe it would be possible to achieve a similar thing with a `tf.TensorArray` and `tf.while_loop` for dynamically sized tensors.